# Beginner Docker docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn, docker-machine

I'm going through [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/) and I've successfully got the stack up and running.

What's bugging me is that when I change my code (in the `web` service) on my host, it **does** automatically make the changes when I reload the page in the browser. I don't understand why it's doing that. Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - redis:redis
  volumes:
    - ./web:/usr/src/app
    - ./web/static:/usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  environment:
    DEBUG: 'true'
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

redis:
  restart: always
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  volumes:
    - redisdata:/data
```

---

I didn't think that this was `gunicorn` doing the reloading because I believe `gunicorn` needs the `--reload` flag to actually do hot reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line means that you are mapping locations on your host to locations within your web container.

```
  volumes:
    - ./web:/usr/src/app
    - ./web/static:/usr/src/app/static
```

Therefore any time you change you change code in the .web directory, it is updated within the container.  If you don't want that to happen then you need to copy those directories when you build your container by specifying that in Dockerfile for that container.

Comment: Thank you, and makes sense. Why does gunicorn have a `--reload` flag then? And also when using servers like `waitress` or even the built in django `runserver`, it's almost as if a reload needs to happen for the code to actually be reflected.

Comment: I believe this happens because you have your environment variable `DEBUG: true`.

Comment: That may affect `settings.py` within Django but why would that affect `gunicorn` which is serving the files.